# Creating reactive extension for Alamofire and Argo

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire, reactive-cocoa, argo

Hi I have problem with my reactive extension for Alamofire

Here is:

```
extension Alamofire.Manager{

    func rac_jsonRequest<T : Decodable, G : ErrorType>(method: Alamofire.Method,_ URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL, headers: [String: String]? = nil) -> SignalProducer<T,G> {

        SignalProducer<T,G> { sink, disposable in
            let request = self.request(method, URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value{
                    if let decoded : T = decode(JSON){ //ERROR THIS
                        sink.sendNext(decoded)
                        sink.sendCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }
            disposable.addDisposable({request.cancel()})
        }
    }
}
```

I obtain this error:

> No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'T?'

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the generic `T` not being complete/strict enough on the associated type. The `decode` function you're trying to use type is specified like so:

```
func decode<T: Decodable where T == T.DecodedType>(_ object: AnyObject) -> T?
```

The extra `where` clause is what's missing from your implementation. Changing it to this should fix it:

```
func rac_jsonRequest<T : Decodable, G : ErrorType where T == T.DecodedType>(method: Alamofire.Method,_ URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL, headers: [String: String]? = nil) -> SignalProducer<T,G> {
```